# Problem with export model .fbx - I get empty file

Tags: modeling, texturing

Hi i try export my model house to substance painter.

[image]

When i choose export .fbx next "export seected" I get empty file :

[image]

but when I create a simply cube, this export work. Please help what I can do ?

Comment: I store most of my files in obj or fbx, the exporters work fine for most cases, so I'm pretty sure there's somethign wrong with your approach. I see the model is offset from the center of the grid, could it be that you are simply not seeing it as it is outside of the camera view on your viewer?
If not add more information please.

Comment: I hope that's about you this :  https://image.prntscr.com/image/tByHc9oiRSCiYReYwiAMAQ.png